# Help Identifying a LEGO plane

Tags: aircraft-identification

I need some help identifying a LEGO plane.

The LEGO set [7292](http://brickset.com/sets/7292-1/Propeller-Adventures), *Propeller Adventures*, features a twin engine airplane, with conventional landing gear, and a bubble canopy.  There are no pontoons on the wings

Assuming it's based on a real plane, does anyone have any ideas?

[image: 7292 Propeller Adventures]

Comment: Related: [On what plane is 7292 Propellor Adventures based?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2913/3163)

Comment: Being a Lego fan for over 30 years, I highly doubt that it is based on any real life aircraft. Lego doesn't hide if a model is based after something from real life ([examples](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Architecture-ByTheme)).

Comment: The tail surfaces are far too small for any real airplane.

Comment: I'd like to know how this question doesn't appear to be about aviation.  It's about identifying an aircraft.  I mean, there's an entire tag about identifying aircraft.  The ideal place to ask about something like this is here, in a community of aircraft and aviation experts, not a community of toy enthusiasts.

Comment: @Nick2253 It has been put on hold because the model is a toy, not an actual airplane. The tag you mentioned is primarily used for pictures of airplanes.

Comment: In 8 months, about 100 views and no answer on the lego site, in 5 days, slightly more than 100 views but many suggestions on the aviation site. Seems to indicate that it really is an aviation question…

Comment: @Relaxed You can certainly vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Farhan I don't think I can, no (low rep).

Comment: @Relaxed Well you are not far from [that](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: @Relaxed I agree with you, and I voted to re-open.  I will admit that it is a bit of an edge case, but, I do think it is an interesting aviation related question.  One that this community could be very helpful in answering (as has proven to be the case, 2 answers already) and one that people find interesting (760 visits so far...)  I would like to see more evidence behind why it would be a particular craft (rather than just pure speculation), but I still find it interesting...  So I've nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few which are similar on some points, although all have at least one issue. In the end I suspect in the end it's just a "generic mid-wing, twin engined WWII fast bomber"

Other than the radial engines, it looks a lot like a de Havilland Mosquito

[image: de Havilland Mosquito]

Or perhaps a Junkers Ju88

[image: Junkers Ju88]

Or a CAC Woomera, at a stretch

[image: CAC Woomera]

Answer (score 3):

Could also be a Ki-45

[image]

or except for the tail a BR-20

[image]

Comment: It doesn't quite fit, to my eyes, with the forward swept wings, top turret and pointy nose... then again, you could say similar about my suggestions.

Comment: Either way the oval wings, rotary engines and tail dragger put the plane in WWII era, a lot of planes were designed during that era that copied from each other, so unless the original designer comes along guesses are all we have

Comment: Agreed, Oval-ish wings, Rotary Engines, Mid-wing, tail dragger etc are all pretty common.

Comment: What about the Bristol Beaufighter?

Comment: That did occur to me, but the Beau is very stub-nosed and has a turret, so doesn't fit too well